# Is it possible to add more than one IndoorManager tileset to an Azure Map?

Tags: azure-maps

I have a requirement to show more than one building indoor map on a single Azure Map.  Does Azure Map's Indoor Module support adding more than one tileset to a map?

A single building's indoor map is created using the Azure Indoor Map Creator which results in a single tilesetId.  This is added to an Azure Map using [atlas.indoor.IndoorManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-indoor/atlas.indoor.indoormanager?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest).  I have two different tilesetIds that work when added to a map on their own, but I'm unable to have both visible and selectable individually.

This is the code I use but only the first tileset added is ever shown.

```
      // building 1
      const levelControl = new atlas.control.LevelControl({
        position: "top-right",
      });

      const indoorManager = new atlas.indoor.IndoorManager(map, {
        levelControl: levelControl,
        tilesetId: tilesetId
      });

      // building 2
      const levelControl2 = new atlas.control.LevelControl({
        position: "top-right",
      });

      const indoorManager2 = new atlas.indoor.IndoorManager(map, {
        levelControl: levelControl2, 
        tilesetId: tilesetId2,
      });
```

The indoor manager class itself only appears to support a single tileset so my assumption is that I need a class per tileset, each with its own level control.  However, this only ever renders the first indoor manager.  I've swapped the tilesets around to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indoor manager currently does not support multiple tilesets. To get two buildings showing, you would need to append the conversionId of the second building to an existing dataset. You can then create a new tileset that contains both buildings.

Thanks,

Brendan

Comment: thanks. I'll give that a shot.  Do you know if the Indoor Manager will support multiple buildings in a campus style scenario soon?  We have some use cases where this is a must.

Comment: Also, does your suggestion have any implications for level control if the buildings have different numbers of levels?  Thinking where one building ends at floor 1, and next building goes to level 3 as an example.

Comment: Multiple buildings are supported as long as they are in one dataset. You can add as many buildings as you would like to one dataset. Supporting multiple tilesets is on our roadmap, however there is no ETA at this time. Are there scenarios where you must have multiple tilesets?

Comment: The level control comes into play when you select a building and only impacts the selected building, so switching levels on one building wouldn't impact another.

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I'll mark as answered and get back to you in another question if necessary.  In the meantime, is this the preferred support channel for issues related to Indoor Maps and Creator, or is there another?

Comment: I do have a scenario for multiple tilesets though yes.  I may have two different customers next door to each other and only want to show the indoor buildings for a specific customer.  Would your recommendation here be to use a separate Azure Maps account per customer?