# Please provide detailed explanation to add more than one indoor map to an Azure Map

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I have a requirement of showing different indoor-maps on azure-maps, I found this,
[Is it possible to add more than one IndoorManager tileset to an Azure Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490226/is-it-possible-to-add-more-than-one-indoormanager-tileset-to-an-azure-map), a similar question to what I am looking for, but I am not able to follow it.
Please provide a detailed explanation of the steps required, an example would be very helpful.

Thanks
Satyam

Comment: You can add a comment in the answer verified in the related thread to get more details. Would be good that the answer is updated with more details there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.